# Polyfill for ie

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, babeljs, polyfills

I'm trying to add a `polyfill` to my `vue.js 2.0/Laravel5.3` application because in internet explorer 11 I receive an error:

```
vuex requires a Promise polyfill in this browser.
```

So I've followed the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) I'm using ecm 6 so I did:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill
```

And added this at the top in my **bootstrap.js**:

```
import "babel-polyfill";
```

But still the same error in Internet explorer. What should I do or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Ordinarily my up-votes go without explanation, but I just want to commend you on a well-written, researched and explained question. While I can't help you with the question, due to unfamiliarity, I really wanted to offer explanation as an incentive to others that might view this question, whether now or in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I"m glad to hear that.

Comment: It's worth asking: what version of IE are you using? And can you confirm that you're in the correct standards mode? Finally, have you checked that bootstrap (and the polyfill) have finished loading when the error occurs? eg are you loading everything in the right order?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, it's also possible to use `es6-promise` if you get totally stuck: https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Comment: I'm using ```IE 11``` and the correct standard mode is active. Everything is being loaded fine (checked it). @craig_h Going to that one.

Comment: I dont know about vue.js, but i use a polyfill for the Promise as well as follow: import Promise from "babel-polyfill". May it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Webpack, find your `webpack.base.conf.js` file (mine was in the `build` folder), or the equivalent webpack configuration file, then modify the app entry variable to include `babel-polyfill` at the start so it looks something like this:

```
entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', ...]
  },
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: Provided suggestion of using babel-polyfill worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

@doulmi

Add this to your package.json file:

```
 "babel-polyfill": "^6.20.0"
```

After that `npm install`.

Add this at the top of you main js file:

```
import "babel-polyfill";
```

Compile everything. That should work.

Comment: This answer might be more "proper" than the one I gave, which is a bit hackish.